# Rewrite basic $_GET variable to friendly URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I know questions similar to this are common. I just don't even know where to begin with rewrite rules with the /'s and .'s I don't know how to retrofit other peoples solutions to mine. Onto my situation:

I am using a basic get on the index.php file that looks like

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=about
```

I want to rewrite that to

```
http://www.example.com/about
```

I know this is fairly simple rewrite wise, but its just a totally different language which I have tried and failed to comprehend. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: So the way this should work is that if I send the user to /about the server will rewrite it for itself as /index.php?page=about .Correct? I ask cause I tried the code and it didn't work for me. I've have mod_rewrite working in other areas of my server so I know does not have to do with overrides and such. Also tested to make sure the whole .htaccess file is being written wrong. For some reason I just can't get this directory to rewrite anything.

Answer (score 1):

Or even:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule ^(?!index.php\b).*   index.php?page=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Note:

- You should always set the `RewriteBase` in an `.htaccess` file.
- I've generalised this so that `index.php` picks up *any* string which isn't mapping to a real file
- The `(?!index.php\b)` is a regexp which says "but don't match to `index.php`"
- You will need the [QSA] flag if your requests can contain request parameters.  This merges them.